# landing page to mobile site?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

Hi I have a landing page which i aim to split into 4 sections and my plan is for a mobile device such as a small android phone to load the first then when the user scrolls down or up to load the next part, is this possible and how would I go about doing it? Could I use jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

if u just need to partition the screen in 4 parts and want the other parts to load on scroll u wont need jquery mobile just for it. (though their r loads of places where it can make your life simpler)
You can just detect the scroll event (or swipe) and then detect the height by which the screen scrolled and load and append or prepend the page as required. tell me if u need help with the code

Comment: hi ghostCoder that sounds great but what about different devices having different proportions. I would be grateful if you could help with the code as i wouldn't know where to start im new to mobile development.

Comment: if u r using jquery mobile to style your page then your design will be fluid and the elements will adjust according to the screen sizes.